# NoSuchElementException error for which I have created a catch clause

Tags: java

```
            int num_lines = 0;
            try {
                if (file_stream.hasNextInt()) //line 81
                {
                    num_lines = file_stream.nextInt();
                }
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                System.err.println("The input is not valid and cannot be processed.");                  
            }
```

I keep getting this error even though I seem to have accounted for it in the code. The file_stream file is empty in this test case, so I wanted to see if the program would catch the error and apparently it fails to do so:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Program1.main(Program1.java:81)
```

Comment: Works fine for me with an empty file--with an empty file the nextInt code won't even run.

Comment: @dpryor Is nextInt() method called before this try block?

Answer (score 1):

`NoSuchElementException` exception will be thrown when the iteration has no more elements where as the `Scanner` class methods return tokens.

From [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) :

> A simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings
>   using regular expressions.
>
> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
>   which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be
>   converted into values of different types using the various next
>   methods.

For instance,

```
List<Integer> ints=new ArrayList<Integer>();
try
{
  int  value=ints.iterator().next();
}catch(NoSuchElementException ex)
 {
   System.out.println(ex);
 }
```

Comment: Note that in his code, he checks `if (file_stream.hasNextInt())`, so it should never fail.

Comment: @RyanStewart - It is possible that nextInt() or next() method is invoked before the try block.

Comment: Anything is possible, but since the OP appears to be aware of the need to protect against running out of elements--see the conditional and the try/catch--it seems unlikely he'd skip over a nearby unprotected call and ask why a protected one isn't working. Besides, that's not what your answer says. You just provide code that's the same as what's already in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking at the wrong place in the code. Unless you have multiple threads reading from that stream, there's no way you can get a NoSuchElementException after hasNextInt() returns true.

Comment: if (file_stream.hasNextInt()) ; That's line 81 in the code the error refers to.

Comment: @dpryor `hasNextInt` doesn't throw a `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: @dpryor: what he said. You probably need to recompile.